# prevent browser from requesting default route

Tags: backbone.js, express, routes

I am building Backbone abd Expressjs application.

When the page loads, I want to view my home page, which will be loaded with ajax from a local, public folder. Problem is that the browser is sending request to server and I got response **Cannot GET /**

And on server side, in app.js file there is no route for **/**

I made that route in a Backbone **router.js** file.

```
routes: {
    "":"home
}
```

In short, I want **index.html** to be loaded from client, not from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to place **index.html** file inside of public folder.
Now, it can be loaded and manipulated locally with ajax ( like a template ). Also **hash** in the url will work ( no request to server ) - that was my main issue.